# How can I improve the robustness of my Fire Detection algorithm in openCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project to detect fire in CCTV or any other surveillance cameras. Up till now I have completed the following stages;

1. Convert the RGB into HSV
2. Sliced out the Value matrix from HSV
3. Applied background subtraction model from openCV () to separate the foreground which is area of the fire.
4. Applied morphological operations on the extracted foreground.
5. Extracted contours from the foreground.
6. ANDed the contour mask to original HSV

Now I am getting an HSV image where there are shades of fire color's in the Region of Interest (ROI)

I am getting the following output on the video where there is fire.

[output with mask ANDed with RGB original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY3Yy.jpg)

[output with mask ANDed with HSV image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHgYD.jpg)

My problem is **I am getting such output on videos where there is no fire but shades of red, yellow and orange are present with high intensity. How can I improve it further by eliminating false positives?**

EDIT: [sample video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNEXZVKl5Vs&t=561s) on which I am working on

Comment: can you post a video as an example for us to work on?

Comment: Hi @IanChu thank you for the comment, edited the question to add a link of sample video...also pasting here -->>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNEXZVKl5Vs&t=561s